# When button gets clicked, make it dissapear, randomely change bg color and load text from database?

Tags: android, button, colors

I am busy creating an app. I succeeded in creating the button with a custom font and all. Now what I'd want is that when I click the button, it must disapear, the background color of the view must randomely change and text must be loaded from an database.

How does one go about this?

Matthew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the disappearing can be make like this:

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click - Disappear in your case...
             v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //can be View.GONE as well...
         }
     });
 }
}
```

Then for the background I guess you can create an array with all the colors you want (or something that generates a random HEX code) and then do `setBackground(X)` where X is the HEX code that you just generated... You need to specify more about the database part though.

Comment: Added it to my code, but content_layout_id is red? Also where exactyly do I put the setBackground(x) ?

Comment: EDIT* The dissapearing works perfectly, I had to put it in my already existing onCreate. The background color changing is still unclear to me though..

Comment: You need execute the code to change the color inside the `onClick` listener of the button...